# 'Jemand hat seinen' or 'jemand hat ihren'?

Tags: gender, pronoun, learning

Which is right? Or both?

1. Gestern war ich in der Schlange. Jemand hat mir ihren Platz gegeben.
2. Gestern war ich in der Schlange. Jemand hat mir seinen Platz gegeben.

Is jemand masculine or feminine or neuter or it depends?

Answer (score 6):

Beide Varianten sind möglich, können aber je nach Sprechsituation etwas anderes bedeuten.

Zunächst einmal: *Mein*, *dein*, *sein*, *ihr*, *unser*, *euer* sind [besitzanzeigende Fürwörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessiv). Welches besitzanzeigende Fürwort in einer bestimmten Sprechsituation das geeignete ist, richtet sich normalerweise nach der betreffenden [grammatischen Person](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_(Grammatik)), deren Besitz (Eigentum, Verwandschaft, etc.) angezeigt werden soll.

#### Jemand ≠ Besitzer

Nehmen wir einmal an, jemand weist mir einen Platz zu, jedoch nicht seinen eigenen, sondern den einer anderen Person. Dann zeigt das besitzanzeigende Fürwort an, welche grammatische Person hinter dem ursprünglichen Besitzer steckt:

> Jemand hat mir *meinen* / *deinen* / *seinen* / *ihren* / *unseren* / *euren* Platz gegeben.

#### Jemand = Besitzer

Nehmen wir nun an, *jemand* ist *selber* Besitzer eines Platzes und weist mir eben diesen Platz zu. Dann ist das [unbestimmte Fürwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen) *jemand* gleichzeitig die grammatische Person des besitzanzeigenden Fürworts. Und da *jemand* zur 3. Person Singular gehört und maskulinen Geschlechts ist, lautet das richtige besitzanzeigende Fürwort für diese Sprechsituation *sein*:

> *Jemand* <sub>[3. Pers. Sg., m.]</sub> hat mir *seinen* <sub>[3. Pers. Sg., m.]</sub> (eigenen) Platz gegeben.
>
> <sub>(Mit dem Wörtchen *eigenen* lässt sich die Sprechsituation eindeutig machen.)</sub>

Ein anderes besitzanzeigendes Fürwort, wie zum Beispiel *ihr*, wäre in dieser Sprechsitation formal unrichtig, weil dann die grammatischen Personen nicht übereinstimmen würden:

> <s>*Jemand* <sub>[3. Pers. Sg., m.]</sub> hat mir *ihren* <sub>[3. Pers. Sg., f.]</sub> (eigenen) Platz gegeben.</s>

#### Constructio ad sensum

Allerdings kommt es, vor allem in letzter Zeit, zuweilen vor, dass man sich bei bekanntem natürlichen Geschlecht nach diesem richtet anstatt nach dem grammatischen Geschlecht. Man nennt dies *Konstruktion nach dem Sinn* oder [*Constructio ad sensum*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructio_ad_sensum). Wäre der Jemand bekanntermaßen eine Frau, so wäre der Satz

> *Jemand* hat mir *ihren* eigenen Platz gegeben.

nach dem Sinn konstruiert.

Comment: As a followup, what if there are two sentences? E.g. is it correct to say *Jemand gab mir eine Eintrittskarte für das Konzert. Das war sehr nett von ihr.* I take it that the balance tips more in favor of *sensum* the farther the pronoun is from where the person was first introduced.

Comment: +1 for constructio ad sensum.

Answer (score 4):

Zur Möglichkeit unterschiedlicher Bedeutungen und zum Zusammenhang zwischen Besitzer und ihn bezeichnendes Indefinitpronomen, siehe die m.E. hervorragende Antwort von @BjörnFriedrich.

Ich möchte hier nur auf den Fall *Jemand = Besitzer* eingehen und m.E. wichtige Details hinzufügen.

#### Aus der Sicht der Grammatik

Warum ist *jemand* maskulin?

Man könnte argumentieren, dass *jemand* von *Mensch* kommt<sup>1</sup> und daher maskulin ist. Ebenso könnte man (wie @GunterSchadow in seiner Antwort) argumentieren, dass *jemand* genderindifferent ist und daher *wie-maskulin* verwendet wird<sup>2</sup>. In beiden Fällen gehört aus Sicht der Grammatik zum Indefinitpronomen *jemand* (als Besitzer) das besitzanzeigende Fürwort *sein*.

#### Aus der Sicht der Semantik

Damit etwas *sinngemäß* ist, muss es zuerst einmal einen Sinn ergeben.

@BjörnFriedrich weist in seiner Antwort der Vollständigkeit halber auf die *Konstruktion nach dem Sinn* (Constructio ad Sensum) hin, also eine

*Satzkonstruktion, bei der sich das Prädikat oder Attribut nicht nach der grammatischen Form des Subjekts, sondern nach dessen Sinn richtet.*<sup>3</sup>

Solche Konstruktionen entstehen durch sehr enge Bindung einer Formulierung an das damit beschriebene innere Bild, sind dann (insbesondere in literarischen Texten) durchaus sinnvoll und können sogar gezielt eingesetzt werden, um mit wenigen Worten dramaturgische Effekte zu erzielen.

- Beispiel 1:

  > Der Polizist bemerkte *das Mädchen* hinter dem Baum, aber als er noch einmal zurückschaute, war *sie* schon weg.

  Um [grammatische Kongruenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kongruenz_(Grammatik)) herzustellen, müsste es heißen

  > ... war *es* schon weg.

  Da *Mädchen* ein weibliches Wesen bezeichnet, gibt es zwischen *das Mädchen* und *sie* aber semantische Kongruenz. Daher ist die Konstruktion sinngemäß richtig, auch wenn sie gegen die Regel der grammatischen Kongruenz verstößt.
- Beispiel 2:

  > *Der ganze Haufen* stürzte auf ihn zu. *Sie warfen* ihn in heißen Teer und federten ihn dann.

  *Der Haufen* ist maskulin und es müsste daher formal richtig heißen:

  > ... *Er warf* ihn in heißen Teer ...

  Da *der Haufen* hier aber offenbar eine Gruppe von Menschen bezeichnet, die vorher schon einmal erwähnt wurde, gibt es auch hier semantische Kongruenz.

Aus Sicht der Semantik sind diese Konstruktionen also nicht fehlerhaft, sondern könnten als Stilmittel betrachtet werden.

**Im Fall von *jemand* ist das anders.**

*Jemand* "... bezeichnet irgend eine Person, die man **nicht näher bestimmen** kann oder will ..."<sup>1</sup>

> Jemand hat mir *ihren* Platz gegeben.

Es macht absolut keinen Sinn (und ist damit auch nicht sinn-gemäß), im ersten Wort des Satzes durch die Verwendung des Wortes *jemand* von allen Eigenschaften der Person zu abstrahieren, nur um anschließend ausgerechnet das biologische Geschlecht zu konkretisieren. Wenn das bedeutsam ist, kann man auch gleich mit dem Subjekt des Satzes *eine Frau* oder *ein Mann* sagen. Sofern man nicht selbst verwirrt ist, führt man mit solchen Zickzack-Formulierungen zumindest den Empfänger der Nachricht buchstäblich an der Nase herum. Das ist weniger als nur schlechter Stil. Es ist umständliche, zeitraubende, ermüdende Information und es ist mehr als fraglich, ob eine solche Konstruktion überhaupt als *Constructio ad Sensum* bezeichnet werden kann.

Hier gibt es weder grammatische noch semantische Kongruenz. Die Information zum biologischen Geschlecht des mit *jemand* bezeichneten Menschen wird vom Subjekt gezielt abgezogen und kommt dann durch das verwendete Personalpronomen zur Hintertür wieder herein.

Letztlich sollten wir nicht vergessen, dass Sprache im Alltag der Kommunikation, also dem Austausch von Information dient und man sich nicht selbst von hinten in die Brust schießen sollte, nur weil man einen Weg gefunden hat, wie das geht.

Die Formulierung

> Jemand hat mir *ihren* Platz gegeben.

kann (von einem kompetenten Sprecher) im Grunde kaum etwas anders heißen als: *Jemand bot mir den Platz der Frau an, die ich eben schon einmal erwähnt habe.*

#### Political correctness

Auch wenn mir die Politisierung der Grammatik oft zu weit geht, hielte ich es rein logisch durchaus für gerechtfertigt, die Verwendung von *jemand* mit anschließender Konkretisierung des biologischen Geschlechts als sexistisch zu bewerten. Mit der Verwendung von *jemand* als Subjekt des Satzes wird prominent herausgestellt, dass sämtliche Eigenschaften der Person vollkommen uninteressant sind. Anschließend nur auf das Geschlecht noch einmal explizit hinzuweisen, könnte man geradezu als Definition von Sexismus bewerten, denn die Reduktion auf das biologische Geschlecht liegt hier nicht in der Sprache begründet, sondern ist explizit herbeigeführt.

---

1 [dwds.de/wb/jemand](https://www.dwds.de/wb/jemand)
2 [Prof. Dr. Peter Gallmann: Zum Genus bei Personenbezeichnungen. Jena 2019/20](http://homepages.uni-jena.de/%7Ex1gape/Wort/Wort_Nomen_Genus_Personen.pdf)
3 [https://www.dwds.de/wb/Constructio ad Sensum](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Constructio%20ad%20Sensum)

Comment: "Jemand hat mir ihren Platz gegeben" mag zwar heutzutage vorkommen, klingt aber schrecklich. Falls jemand Wert darauf Wert legt, das Geschlecht des jemands zu nennen, sollte er (nicht sie) die Formulierung "Eine Frau hat mir ihren Platz gegeben" verwenden.

Answer (score 3):

It's "seinen", because its abstract, there is no gender. And "seinen" could work for a neutral too (e.g. "Das Schwein hat seinen Platz beschmutzt.") If you wanted to say that it was a woman who traded her place with you, you'd say "eine Frau hat mir ihren Platz angeboten." Of course these customs are now all revised by politically correct language policing, you find people pushing pronouns over to the feminine, sometimes every other, sometimes all, and sometimes "seinen/ihren", but it still would sound forced.

Comment: The example with the woman might be a bit misleading because it abets the confusion of *grammatical* and *biological* gender. The pronoun *ihren* is used because the word *Frau* ist feminine, not because it is a woman. A better example analog to masculine but generic *jemand* would be *Eine Person hat mir **ihren** Platz angeboten*, where it is *ihren* even if the person is a man.

Comment: The same issue exists in English, "Someone asked me to give up my place in line last night. I thought about it and then gave it to her/him/them." Presumably the speaker would know the gender of the person who was given the place in line and would use the appropriate pronoun. If the gender is truly unknown or the person is  hypothetical then in English the plural "them" is often used. In English or German rephrasing is also an option: *Eine Frau hat mir ihren Platz gegeben./Ein Mann hat mir seinen Platz gegeben.*

Comment: @RDBury Actually in German the gender of the pronoun to be used is clear because *jemand* is *grammatically* masculine.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus -- I was comparing with English where gender is the 'natural' gender, not grammatical gender. I was saying that presumably you'd know if the person was a man or a woman. If you're talking about a hypothetical random person whose gender is unspecified then you usually use the plural in English; German is, or course, different, and is covered in the answers.

Comment: The use of the plural in English to avoid gender assignment is also new-speak. I doubt this was done before a couple of decades ago. "Someone offered me his seat" or "her seat", but some*one* being one could not offer *their* seat.

Answer (score 2):

Like other pronouns such as «wer», «jemand» has traditionally been masculine – exactly like English “who”, “somebody” etc.

With growing awareness for gender stereotypes expressed in language, there are people who no longer deem sentences like the following to be acceptable:

1. Jemand hat seinen BH liegen gelassen.
2. Somebody has forgotten his bra.

For the reasons Björn Friedrich has explained, simply using the feminine possessive is ambiguous. It may indicate that «jemand»/«somebody» is a woman, or it may indicate that the forgetful person is different from the woman owning the bra:

3. Jemand hat ihren BH liegen gelassen.
4. Somebody has forgotten her bra.

In English, you can leave the gender unspecified by using [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they):

5. Somebody has forgotten their bra.

Singular they is not possible in German because the plural «sie/ihren» is identical to the feminine singular «sie/ihren».

If you want to use «jemand» in German without specifying the gender or using ambiguous expressions, you have to use circumlocutions like the following:

6. Jemand hat den eigenen BH vergessen.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quoting from Wordreference<sup>([1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ich-sehe-jemanden-der-die.2827122/))</sup>, and fully agree. Duden Online does not comment on that issue.
(The summary is: It's traditionally masculine. Nowadays some may start to make a difference. Better is to avoid *jemand* for obvious sentences talking about women, and use different paraphrases.)

---

Ich zitiere aus dem Forum von Wordreference<sup>([1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ich-sehe-jemanden-der-die.2827122/))</sup>, dem ich voll zustimme. Duden Online hält sich da bedeckt (und fein raus?):

"Traditionellerweise ist *jemand* **maskulin**. Es ist aber durchaus möglich, dass heutzutage manche eine Unterscheidung zwischen maskulin und feminin machen.
In einer Sprachprüfung würde ich das Wort auf jeden Fall als maskulin behandeln; in anderen Fällen ist es eine ideologische Entscheidung, was man macht.
Allerdings glaube ich, die traditionelle Variante überwiegt nach wie vor.

jemand ist männlich (grammatikalisches Geschlecht).

> Diese Frau ist jemand, den man ernst nehmen muss.
> Ich habe neben jemand(em) im Flugzeug gesessen, der schön war. Es war die Miss World.

Vgl.

> Ich habe neben jemand Schönem gesessen.
> Ich habe neben jemandem Schönem gesessen.
> Ich habe neben jemandem Schönen gesessen.

​Alle drei sind richtig und sagen übers natürliche Geschlecht nichts aus.

... aus ... geschilderten Gründen nie "jemand" verwenden würde, wenn ich definitiv über eine Frau spräche. (Das ist mir an Beispielsätzen mit "wer" deutlich geworden; Thread).

> Ich habe im Flugzeug neben einer sehr schönen Frau gesessen.
> Ich habe mit einer Frau gesprochen, die mir geholfen hat."